# Maya Qt 5 (pyside2) and docking

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

I’m relatively new to PySide , comfortable enough with creating a handful of modules and classes .

I have a UI working well , currently running it imported into maya , which launches the QDialog class

I now want to figure out how to ‘dock’ this if a user drags it into the maya UI, or wants to pop it out

This is where I’m completely lost, the autodesk example here

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-SDK/files/GUID-66ADA1FF-3E0F-469C-84C7-74CEB36D42EC-htm.html

Gives some primers on what to use , and I’ve tried following it , but the dockable=True argument is not understood by the UI

Also , I’d rather understand what I am doing rather than copy pasting it blindly

Can anyone steer me to some answers ? There’s are related answers on here already but they are for non-qt it older maya versions

Thanks

Comment: This worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563031/dockable-window-in-maya-with-pyside-clean-up